# Laravel mimes validation always called even if no input file is uploaded (Not used required rule)

Tags: php, laravel, validation, mime

I have used single validation rule only for file input field. That is mimes rule. I wanted to skip this rule if no file is uploaded, so i have not used 'required' rule. But it is always showing mime type message even if no file is uploaded. I have just added required rule for testing , at that time it shown required error message. This problem is only when submitting form using ajax with jquery.form.js

Comment: Add `sometimes` to your rule.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sometimes` validation type for that.

```
'file' => 'sometimes|mimes:jpeg,png'
```

---

**Validating When Present**

In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list.

[Official Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sometimes` rule.

```
'photo' => 'sometimes|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
```

You can check more about it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: Still not working in my form. I think the problem is when using ajax form submission using jquery.form js

Answer (score 1):

I've issued the same problem recently with ajax uploading, and handled the file validation using

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'invitation_message' => 'required'
    ];

    if (request()->hasFile('invitation_excel_sheet')) {
        $rules = array_merge($rules, [
            'invitation_excel_sheet' => 'mimes:xlsx,csv'
        ]);
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `exclude_if` in model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'link' => 'sometimes',
        'newPdf' => 'exclude_if:link,null|mimes:pdf',
    ];
}
```