# Image form validation with Laravel and Vue

Tags: php, laravel

I have an image field that should not be required, but should be limited to possible file types
But, if I validate mimes, submitting the form without an image does not work

```
request()->validate([
       'name' => ['required'],'name' => ['required'],
       'type' => ['required'],'master_id' => ['required'],
       'description' => ['required'],
       'whom_id' => ['required'], 'short_description' => ['required'],
       'image' => ['mimes:jpg,bmp,png','max:3072'],
        ]);
```

```
if(request()->image){
        $ext = request()->file('image')->extension();//Получение расширения файла
        $path = request()->file('image')->storeAs('image', $course->id.'mainImage.'.$ext);
        $course->image = $path;
 }
```

[image: validate err]

Comment: Try adding `sometimes|` in front, Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44265107/367456 (may depend on how you submit the form, see as well [Conditionally Adding Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) and the note therein).

Comment: @hakre
Doesn't work for me ('image' => ['sometimes','mimes:jpg,bmp,png','max:3072'],)
form submit with vue

Comment: If you're still in for another try, then also add `nullable|` in front and see if there are any changes. I've picked that from [A Note On Optional Fields](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields).

Comment: And btw. which laravel version, I paste 5.x links all the time but have no clue if it is the version you have in use. Just FYI.

Comment: @hakre Latest but not least, I'm looking into the documentation of my version for your advice.
nullable worked for me, thanks!
Post as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally for standard form submits, [the answer is `sometimes`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44265107/367456), however you're submitting by Vue, so it required `nullable`.

```php
    'image' => ['nullable', 'mimes:jpg,bmp,png','max:3072'],
```

Mind the [Note On Optional Fields](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields).